# How do I create a script to play one random video from a designated folder?

Tags: windows-7, script

I have a folder full of videos, and would like to assign a script to a shortcut that I can click to open one at random in MPC-HC.  I am running Windows 7.

Ideally, it would just be a script to open a random file in the folder in which the script file is placed.  Then I could just place one in any folder I wanted, and set a shortcut to the script.

Comment: What are the extensions of the video files you would want to have picked at random?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that sounds like fun.  :-)

Make a file named **PlayRandom.bat** and paste the following script into it.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
CD /D %~dp0
Set Count=0
For /F "tokens=*" %%f In ('Dir /A-D /B *.txt') Do (Set /A Count=!Count!+1)
Set /A Skip=%Random%%%%Count%
If %Skip%==0 (Set Skip=) Else (Set Skip=skip=%Skip%)
Set RandomFile=
For /F "%Skip% tokens=*" %%f In ('Dir /A-D /B *.txt') Do (If "!RandomFile!"=="" Set RandomFile=%%f)
Start "%RandomFile%"
EndLocal
```

Change `*.txt` in each `For` line to whatever file extension your movies use.  You can write multiple extensions separated by spaces, for example `*.mpg *.avi *.divx`

The `Start` line will open the file in the default program.  You may want to change this to run your movie player, such as:

```
"C:\Program Files\MPC-HC\MPC-HC.exe" "%RandomFile%"
```

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script selects a random video from the script's folder and plays it

1. Save the following code as *somefilename.ps1* inside your movie folder. Note the extension `.ps1`

   ```
   $formats = @("*.avi","*.mp4","*.flv","*.mpg","*.wmv","*.mpeg","*.mov")
   $dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
   gci "$dir\*" -include $formats -recurse | Get-Random -Count 1 | Invoke-Item
   ```
2. Create a shortcut to your *powershell.exe*. Default path on Windows 7 is

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
   ```
3. Modify the target line of your shortcut and append this to execute the Powershell script

   ```
   -executionpolicy bypass -File "D:\your\video\path\somefilename.ps1"
   ```

What to adjust

- Remove `-recurse` if you want to search only in your rootfolder and not in subfolders too
- Expand the `$formats` list if you have exotic file container formats

Used commands: [Split-Path](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx), [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx), [Get-Random](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730929.aspx), [Invoke-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176882.aspx)